# REST API Key and Value for Python

Tags: python, mysql, json, rest, api

I am aware that there are several ways of exposing your data for REST API consumption purpose on Python. However, the two methods that I used seemed to have issues with generating the key for the resulting values. Here are the two methods that I used to build my REST API:

**First Method**

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL

mysql = MySQL()
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = 'user'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = 'fakepassword'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'router'

mysql.init_app(app)

@app.route('/api/v1/routerstatus', methods=['GET'])
def get():
        cursor = mysql.connect().cursor()
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM dm_routerstatus ORDER BY 
status_update_time DESC LIMIT 100;')
        rv = cursor.fetchall()
        return jsonify(rv)

if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
        app.run(debug=True)
```

**Second Method**

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from json import dumps
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL

*SKIPPED THE DB CREDENTIALS*

mysql = MySQL()
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

mysql.init_app(app)

class Router(Resource):
    def get(self):
        conn = mysql.connect().cursor()
        query = cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM dm_routerstatus ORDER BY 
        status_update_time DESC LIMIT 100;')
        result = {'data': [i[0] for i in query.cursor.fetchall()]}
        return jsonify(result)

api.add_resource(Router, '/api/v1/routerstatus')

if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000)
        app.run(debug=True)
```

and below is an example of the request results of which is missing the key names (column name).

[image: How do I get the key names without typing every single column titles found in the database?]

How do I get the key names without typing every single column titles found in the database? Thanks in advance for the responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a DictCursor (`MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor`)

Comment: Alright. Now I understand. Thanks. I just need to add dict in the query line.
Let's set the second method for example:
`res = [dict((conn.description[i][0], value) for i, value in enumerate(row)) for row in conn.fetchall()]`